# About the construction of semidirect products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

I need help with the following question:

We have $G_0=H_0[N]_\rho$ a semidirect product, and $\pi:H\to H_0$ an epimorphism such that $K=\ker(\pi)\unlhd H$, and $H/K\cong H_0$.

We have to construct a natural semidirect product $G=H[N]_{\rho'}$, and check that $K\unlhd G$, and $G/K\cong G_0$.

Finally, using this method, we have to construct groups of the form $C_4[C_3]$ and $Q_8[C_3]$, starting from $G_0=S_3$.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: I am not understanding your notation. By $H_0\lbrack N\lbrack_{\rho}$ do you mean the semidirect product $H_0\rtimes N$ induced by the automorphism $\rho$? ($\rtimes$ is the standard notation, where $H_0$ is acting on $N$ by the automorphism $\rho$). I am also unsure where $K$ fits in. Are you wanting to form a semidirect product $H_0\rtimes K$?

Comment: I didn't know the standard notation, since i have just started studying semidirect product... so I am a bit lost with all of this :S
I think that with $G_0=H_0[N]_\rho$ we mean $N\unlhd G_0$, $H_0\leq G_0$ and $H_0\cap N=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $G_0=N\rtimes_{\rho}H_0$, where $\rho:H_0\to Aut(N)$ is a group homomorphism. You have another group homomorphism $\rho'=\rho\pi:H\to Aut(N)$ which gives rise to a semidirect product $G=N\rtimes_{\rho'}H$. Define $\varphi:G\to G_0$ by $\varphi(n,h)=(n,\pi(h))$ and show that $\varphi$ is a surjective group homomorphism with $\ker\varphi=\{1_N\}\times K$, so $K\trianglelefteq G$ and $G/K\cong G_0$.

If $G_0=S_3$, then $G_0=C_3\rtimes_{\rho} C_2$, where $\rho:C_2\to Aut(C_3)$ is the only non-trivial homomorphism. Now all you have to do is to choose a surjective group homomorphism $\pi:C_4\to C_2$, respectively $\pi:Q_8\to C_2$.

Comment: Sorry, christmas delay :) Your answer was very useful. Thanks a lot, user!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** An action of $A$ on $B$ corresponds to a map $A\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(B)$. So we know that there exists a map $H_0\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(N)$. Conclude that $H$ acts on $N$, so you have the semidirect product $H\rtimes N$ you are after.

Comment: I don't get your argument, user1729... could you clarify this a bit?

Comment: @Mark What is it that you are unsure about? In a semidirect product $G\rtimes N$ then group $G$ acts on $N$. This corresponds to a map $G\rightarrow\operatorname{Aut}(N)$, which is what I am suggesting you use.

Comment: It's everything clear now, user1729. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: That's okay, sorry for taking so long to reply. If you continue studying group theory then you will realise actions are rather fundamental. So if you can understand this hint then you are in a good place.